# Cmake doesn't correctly parse whitespace in command line parameter with shell script on windows

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, cmake, git-bash

I'm trying to run a shell script, which executes a cmake command. It runs on windows on the git-bash.

My run.sh code looks like this:

```
CMAKE_GENERATOR="'Unix Makefiles'"
performStrict   cmake -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" /path/to/dir/
```

And delivers the following output:

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' /path/to/dir/

CMake Error: Could not create named generator 'Unix
```

I also tried it with (escaped) double quotes. Unfortunately, it gives the same result. Also with many other possible combinations.

Comment: Try `CMAKE_GENERATOR="Unix Makefiles"
performStrict   cmake -G "\"$CMAKE_GENERATOR\""`

Comment: I tried it. Same result.

Comment: What's the error message now?